# Power Bi relations between two tables, one active on inactive

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm in a bit of a jam. Just started with Power BI and relations are a nightmare to figure of tbh.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to connect two tables where both relations are active.

I want the relation between SEROC -> TimeInStatus and also SER -> TimeInStatus. But I have another relation between TimeInStatus -> Issues all connected with Issues_ID.

The issue here is that the connection between SEROC -> TimeInStatus is always inactive. And so I'm stuck and don't know where to even begin...Help would be appreciated.

I tried creating a new table to and I watched a bunch of tutorials on how to but none with similar issues.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfVDUiU8vaU

Comment: @AshokAnumula tnx, for the quick response

Comment: Please add your relationship diagram to your question.  It's unclear from your description why both relationships can't be active.  The rule is that there must be at most one filter flow path between any two tables, and no cycles.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft hi, tnx for the response I figured out how to solve the issue with the yt link above. Also tnx you for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

More than 1 Active relationship between two table is not possible in power bi between two tables. You can create additional column through DAX/Power Query and there you merge all three column with Concatenation operator(DAX) . and then make a relationship it become effective and feasible to work with multiple column relationship at a time.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. I also checked the video in the fist comment which expained that by setting up a dummy/roleplay table you can bypass this issue